# Error: order.by requires an appropriate time-based object PreformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to run this code:

```
minvar.opt <- optimize.portfolio(ExptdRnt, minvar.port, optimize_method = "random",rp = rportfolios)
```

to apply markowitz portfolio optimization. But I encounter this error:

> Error in checkData(R) :    The data cannot be converted into a time
>   series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with
>   one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop =
>   FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as
>   '1985-03-15'.  In addition: Warning message: In if (class(x) ==
>   "numeric") { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used

Comment: Please be aware: photos of code are one of the most useless thing you can add. It is text, always add the information as text then.

Comment: Do you understand the error? What is your question?

Comment: Thank you @AnderBiguri , for the advice .
I want to apply Markowitz optimisation portfolio , i have imported Data ( stoks returns ) From Excel , i have calculated Means and standard deviation with RStudio , After that i have generate random portfolios ... and when  I'm going to do the optimization I encounter the error above .

Comment: Please take the [tour], learn [ask] and [edit] your question, dont add information on comments

Comment: thank you @AnderBiguri , i have just finished the tour , thank you for helping me , henceforth I will put a specifics questions.